# Force reload of page to reflect updated NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I store a password as an `NSUserDefaults` and there is a modal view controller in the app where you can change your password. After changing it, the modal view controller is dismissed returning you to a page that shows the password.

My question is, how can I force this page to show the updated password from `NSUserDefaults` as it is already loaded in the stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement `viewWillAppear` and set the data of your ViewContoller there.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // prepare the view
}
```

Comment: If the device is an iPad, will `viewWillAppear:` be called after a modal view controller is dismissed?

Comment: Don't forget to call `super`.

Comment: That worked.  As a general matter is it better to load the interface in viewWillAppear than viewDidLoad?  Is there anything wrong with loading it in both places? (Would seem inefficient?  Thx!

Comment: Take a look at the UIViewController lifecycle: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eYCHy.jpg will/didAppear will be called every time the view (re-)appears on screen. didLoad will only be called once in the lifetime of a UIViewController.

Answer (score 2):

Present the modalViewController with a completion block and update the password in completion block.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a delegate method that is called every time the password is changed in Modal View Controller. Or simply change it in viewDidAppear so that each time the model view disappears, viewDidAppear will be called and field will be changed accordingly.